# Calling Javascript function from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, function

On my MVC view I have something as below in my Html.BeginForm

```
@if (Html.ViewData.ModelState.Count > 1 && (Html.ViewData.ModelState["SingleUnitBarcode"].Errors.Any() 
{
sectionStyle1 = "red";

    // I WANT TO CALL A JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION HERE , HOW ?
}
```

How do I make a call to a javascript function after the line `sectionStyle1 = "red";`

Comment: Your code does not compile. Missing a `)` at the end of line 1.

Comment: What programming/scripting language you are using?

Comment: Its an MVC project.See edits.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `<script>` tag containing your required javascript. You also have a syntax error in your if statement in that you were missing the ending parenthesis:

```
@{ string sectionStyle1 = null;}
@if(Html.ViewData.ModelState.Count > 1 && (Html.ViewData.ModelState["SingleUnitBarcode"].Errors.Any()))
{
    sectionStyle1 = "red";

<script>
    // Your Javascript code here
    doStuffWith("@sectionStyle1");
</script>
}
```

This will print out the following raw HTML when the `if` condition is met:

```
<script>
    doStuffWith("red");
</script>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
@if (Html.ViewData.ModelState.Count > 1 && 
(Html.ViewData.ModelState["SingleUnitBarcode"].Errors.Any() 
{
sectionStyle1 = "red";

   FunctionName()
}
```

Comment: But i dont see any html code in here? But i think it should work in this way. @PatrickHofman

Comment: That is not JavaScript.